# $sample equivalent in mongodb .find()

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Rather than rewrite queries as `aggregate` expressions to take advantage of the `$sample` option, is there an equivalent method for `.find()` operations. I've not been able to find anything in pymongo that works with find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the $sample aggregation operator only works with aggregation.